# which is the best way to distribute api to different user?

Tags: jar, domain-driven-design, distribution

I have a typical class like this:

```
public class A {
   void run();    //for all users
   void delete(); //for privileged users
}
```

I want to distribute these classes as a single jar to different users, the common users can only see the methods which is permitted and cannot see these high privileged(like delete()), how can i achieve this?
By the way i am a big fan of DDD, which means i donot want these methods to fall apart.

Comment: I don't know if its possilbe to just hide a method in a JAR !  You could restrict access though. Restricting access to certain methods based on roles can be achieved in JavaEE environment by using @RolesAllowed annotation on the method. For your concerns maybe there exists something in SecurityManager. See the *Access Control Enforcement* [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/overview/jsoverview.html)

Answer (score 2):

I end up with this solution:
restrict high privileged method access with private or package access modifier, so common user cannot see them, and privileged user visit these method through reflection.

```
public class A {
   public void run();    //for all users
   void delete(); //for privileged users
}
```

privileged user:
    Reflections.invokeMethod(ins,"run");

Answer (score 0):

Without a access modifier (public/protected/private...) it wont be visible

Comment: i know access modifier cannot achieve what i want, some good ideas?